# How to reply with stationery in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, spell-check, email-signature, stationery

Is it possible to set a default stationery to use when replying to messages in Outlook 2010? Our stationery includes the company letterhead which should be included with all messages.

Previously, we were putting the letterhead in the signature but that caused other hassles. Because the letterhead goes at the top and the signature text is at the bottom and people started typing in the middle, the entire message ended up being part of the signature where the spell-checker doesn't work.

If somebody can suggest an alternate solution with Outlook 2010 that allows a letterhead image to be included at the top, and signature text to be included at the bottom, and spell checking to work, for all new messages and replies, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

File>>Options>>Mail Format>>Stationery and fonts set your stationery there.

Comment: This only works for composing new messages. The stationery is not used for replies.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install a new html stationary
Copy your html template file into the following directory
Documents and Settings > user > AppData > Roaming > Microsoft > Stationery

2) To use it as a mail template
- Click on New Element (next to New Message)
- Select "Message using..."
- Select "More Stationery..."

> your new template should appear there

To remove all default stationery so as to get a clean list showing only your own customized stationary, you have to delete files in the 2 following  different directories :

1) Delete all directories and files in: Program Files > Microsoft Office > Stationery
2) Delete all files in: Program Files > Common Files > microsoft shared > Stationery
Remark: Windows7 won't you let delete these files! You'll be told that you need an authorization from TrustedInstaller. To work around this, you'll need to install a little app called "Take Ownership". Follow the link below to download the app:

http://www.blogsdna.com/2173/add-take-ownership-option-in-right-click-context-menu-of-windows-7.htm

Comment: Hi @Trevor. The fist tip works great (install new html stationery) but after trying to remove the stationeries deleting the 2 directories you mentioned I realized that it's not removing them from Outlook. Any suggestions on how can I remove them? Thanks.